# Blender FBX Import messed up

Tags: modeling, import, .fbx

So I'm trying to port the Voyager model by Eric Flat from 3DS Max in to Blender. And I've tried looking for a possible fix to this, however I've been unable to find a solution.

When I try to import the model to Blender this happens to it[image]

This doesn't happen with other formats other than the 3DS format either. While I can use an OBJ format, the mesh is a little odd with it. I've tried ALT + G as well as clearing the LOC, ROT, SCALE values.

However the model itself isn't like this in 3DS MAX[image]

I'm not sure why is this happening either, I've also ported another model from MAX using an FBX format, and it imported in to Blender completely fine.

These are my import settings[image]

If anyone knows a way to fix this without changing to another format, I'd greatly appreciate the response.

Blender version: 2.79

Comment: There is no need to add 'Fixed' to the question or answer, instead, accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: I can't accept it until tomorrow, the *FIXED* edit was temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mesh parents were off center, and were fixed by moving them to the 3d cursor. Huge thanks to Pte Jack for figuring this out.

Comment: I don't understand. How did you fix it?